# How to resolve the issue " Unfortunately app has been stopped"

Tags: google-play-store

In my android phone how can I fix the above said error. I have tried to wipe the data,cache and dalvik cache but this doesn't seem to work. Can any one tell the best sure shot fix for this annoying issue. This happens mostly with the google applications.

Comment: See the [related Q&A](http://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=+Unfortunately+*+has+been+stopped), then [edit] your question and show us your recent attempts.

Comment: Could you please give us some more information about your device? (Android version, device model, what apps crash)

Comment: Does disabling Google apps or the related app which shows the error popup fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Is your phone rooted? If yes then maybe you would have disabled some of the services of that app using some sort of app. If yes then enable those services back and you will not get the error. I also faced the same issue once and this solved the problem.

Another thing you can do if the above method doesn't work. If the app is a system app then uninstall updates of that app from settings. Update it again(if you need). That's it. Let me know if I helped you or not.